# Interplot labels when interacting a factor

Tags: r, plot, lm, interaction

So I need to plot the interaction of a factor variable using `interplot` in R. I have been able to figure everything out except an important part of it: how to change the label of the factor that gets plotted. Here's a replicable example showing the issue:

```
set.seed(507)
df <- data.frame(
  outcome = sample(1:7, 1000, replace = T),
  scale = sample(1:7, 1000, replace = T),
  dummy = sample(0:2, 1000, replace = T))

# factor the dummy
df$dummyf <- factor(df$dummy)

# linear model
lm.out <- lm(outcome ~ scale * dummyf, data = df)

# interplot
library(interplot)
interplot(lm.out, "dummyf", "scale", plot = T, hist = F, ci = 0.95)
```

Once I plot the interaction here's what I get:

[image]
Now, I need to be able to change the `dummyf1` and `dummyf2` labels in the facets to read essentially `LABEL1` and `LABEL2`. Here's a possible solution I tried but that isn't getting me what I need:

```
# possible solution?
levels(df$dummyf)[levels(df$dummyf) == 1] <- "LABEL1"
levels(df$dummyf)[levels(df$dummyf) == 2] <- "LABEL2"

# linear model
lm.out.1 <- lm(outcome ~ scale * dummyf, data = df)

# interplot
library(interplot)
interplot(lm.out, "dummyf", "scale", plot = T, hist = F, ci = 0.95)
```

I also tried to modify the facets of `ggplot2` since `interplot` uses `ggplot2` but haven't been able to get it to work either. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to modify the [underlying code](https://github.com/sammo3182/interplot/blob/master/R/Interplot_default.R#L207). It just appends integers to the variable name, not levels.

A workaround would look like this:

```
library(interplot)
set.seed(507)
df <- data.frame(
  outcome = sample(1:7, 1000, replace = T),
  scale = sample(1:7, 1000, replace = T),
  dummy = sample(0:2, 1000, replace = T))

# factor the dummy
df$LABEL <- factor(df$dummy)
# df$LABEL <- df$dummyf
lm.out.1 <- lm(outcome ~ scale * LABEL, data = df)
interplot(lm.out.1, "LABEL", "scale", plot = T, hist = F, ci = 0.95)
```